# Randomizing conservative n rows of a dataframe in r

Tags: r

The problem I have is as explained in the title. I want to randomize the top, middle and bottom 3 rows in place. Here is a sample dataframe.

```
> set.seed(7)
> mydf
   Id Name Score Feedback
1  1   AB    11        P
2  2   AA    12        P
3  3   AC    12        P
4  4   AD    31        P
5  5   AE    13        P
6  6   AF    15        P
7  7   AG     9        F
8  8   AH     8        F
9  9   AI    11        P
```

I could take the top, middle and last 3 rows independently and do a randomization and merge them back as follows:

```
# Take conservative 3 rows from mydf 
  top3 <- head(mydf,3)
  middle3 <- mydf[4:6,]
  tail3 <- tail(mydf,3)
# randomize the rows 
  top3r <- top3[sample(nrow(top3)),]
  middle3r <- middle3[sample(nrow(middle3)),]
  tail3r <- tail3[sample(nrow(tail3)),]
# merge them back 
  mydfr <- rbind(top3r, middle3r, tail3r)
> mydfr
   Id Name Score Feedback
2  2   AA    12        P
1  1   AB    11        P
3  3   AC    12        P
6  6   AF    15        P
4  4   AD    31        P
5  5   AE    13        P
7  7   AG     9        F
8  8   AH     8        F
9  9   AI    11        P
```

Is there someway I could achieve the same without going through the manual process of pulling the n rows?

Thank you,

Comment: Depending how general you want to be, `mydf[c(sample(1:3), sample(4:6), sample(7:9), ]`. It could be parameterized more if necessary...

Comment: This indeed is a better approach. Thank you @Gregor. You might want to add the missing `)` before the `,` though.

Comment: @Gregor, Can you please take the time to write your response in the `Answer` so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the same as your code, but without all the intermediate variables.

```
mydf[c(sample(1:3), sample(4:6), sample(7:9)), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way it could be done if you wanted to use `dplyr` (I do like the base solution by @Gregor in the comments though).

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
mydf %>% 
  mutate(grp = rep(1:3, each = 3)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  sample_n(3)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#> # Groups:   grp [3]
#>      Id  Name Score Feedback   grp
#>   <int> <chr> <int>    <chr> <int>
#> 1     1    AB    11        P     1
#> 2     3    AC    12        P     1
#> 3     2    AA    12        P     1
#> 4     6    AF    15        P     2
#> 5     4    AD    31        P     2
#> 6     5    AE    13        P     2
#> 7     9    AI    11        P     3
#> 8     8    AH     8        F     3
#> 9     7    AG     9        F     3
```